# vb.net control attributes

Tags: vb.net, attributes, controls

i have a user defined control that i call in my aspx page. I want to change its attributes on the vb.net code side.
top of aspx page
control -

```
<%@ Register Src="lightbox.ascx" TagName="abc" TagPrefix="uc1" %>
Calling the control in body -
<uc1:abc ID="abc" runat="server" />
```

vb.net page_load -

```
If Session("ased") = True Then
                abc.Attributes.Add("Visible", "true")
            Else
                abc.Attributes.Add("Visible", "false")
            End If
```

On debug mode I see that code does change values according to session but on the control does not pick up the "false" or "true" attribute. I shows the control anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For server side controls, you should be able to use `Visible` property

```
    If Session("ased") = True Then
            abc.Visible = True
        Else
            abc.Visible = False
        End If
```

if you really have to use the attribute, you should be using "display"

```
    If Session("ased") = True Then
            abc.Attributes.Add("display", "block")
        Else
            abc.Attributes.Add("display", "none")
        End If
```